# Why the downvotes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Employee will not come into the office and managers will not enforce it](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/174657/employee-will-not-come-into-the-office-and-managers-will-not-enforce-it)

I am getting a lot of downvotes on this question. I would like to get some feedback on what can I improve to change that.

Comment: First of all I suggest you can start by addressing the comments people have asking for your feedback. Try addressing those concerns in your post, or kindly point the user suggesting to the part where you explain such topic.

Comment: The only possible explanation for the downvotes seems to be the collective sense of outrage at your behaviour and thinking. Particularly, the idea that someone with a broken foot should "just use crutches", even after departmental directors have decided that this remains a legitimate exception to any diktat against remote working.

Comment: Posting on meta by feigning surprise about the number of downvotes is an excellent way to attract even more negative attention.

Comment: What you can improve? Your attitude towards people with a medical condition.

Comment: @Mari-LouA for the sake of precision this was originally posted on main and only [later migrated to meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6955/revisions) (not by OP). Can't really tell if this makes better or worse

Answer (score 32):

Your question wasn't "How should I handle this situation?" or "What should I do differently next time?"

You went straight to "Where in the USA do people value rules?", which implies that people (including 3 managing directors) don't value rules unless they enforce those rules exactly how you want them to be enforced.  You're not open to the possibility that you might be the one in the wrong.

Comment: To be fair, I totally can see OP getting fired for not following doing what he is told, if the memo said there were no exceptions, then there are no exceptions until the memo is corrected. IMO, both managers are being incompetent, since all they need to do is change the memo to include that X person was working remote until X.

Answer (score 26):

I downvoted because I don't like the premise or tone of the question. Premise-wise, it's basically asking us to validate and encourage obsessive, rigid thinking and behavior. Tone-wise, it's effectively a rant in disguise.

Comment: I have to say I'm feeling more strongly about the premise then what you wrote. I think the premise is asking us to further a campaign of harassment and intimidation against a disabled employee (whose managers are okay with this!)

Answer (score 18):

While this site has a rule of assuming good faith, it's fair to assume some of the downvoters thought you were not asking in good faith and were simply trolling.

Comment: Yeah.  IMO either they are trolling or are just a terrible person I would fire in a hot minute if they were in my org.  Assume good faith leads me to choose troll I guess?

Comment: There is only so much good faith that can be assumed by a question worded like that and this one used up all the good faith quota it possibly could then some

Comment: put down the crystal ball.  Poe's law

Comment: I hope he is trolling cause it really looks like he's a troll. What garbage human being would act like this in real life ?

Comment: @PowerCat anyone doing their job while the managers' can't change a memo, apparently or the situation would have been resolved when he hit the first manager, they just didn't do anything besides verbal confirmation, which carries 0 weight since it can't be proven.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't downvote, and I tried to set up an answer as clear and neutral as possible. That being said, think about the following points :

1. Everyone seem to disagree with you
2. Most people (including me) seem to think your behaviour is extremely agressive
3. Instead of answering the commenter's points, you open another thread to complain that everyone is downvoting you

That's typically the behaviour of someone not used to meet opposition. I've got bad news for you : corporate life is full of opportunities when things don't happen as we want. It happens to me all the time, as well, not to have things as I want at work. I do adapt.

You have to adapt and adjust as well. When things obviously are not unfolding as you imagined, then the most likely reason is that your expectations were unrealistic. At my own workplace, my own expectations were unrealistic more than once. I did adjust. It's time for you to learn to do the same, instead of blaming the entire world for not fitting your expectations.

Answer (score 9):

Personally I downvoted for several reasons and I am guessing these also applied to others.

1. You posted that it was your job to check that people returned yet you seem to think that it is your job to force people to return
2. You seem to think it is your job to determine if a reason for working from home is valid or not.
3. You seem to think that it is your job to determine who can and can't work from home.
4. You seem to to think that you have the authority to overrule managing directors who have approved work from home
5. You seem to think that you have the authority to fire people who are working from home if you don't approve of it.

Overall it seems that you seem to think that you are above managing directors and in control of what everyone can and can't do in the company.

As a side note you should hope that no one from your employer finds out about either of these threads as they will not look kindly upon you taking this internal issue public.

Comment: "As a side note you should hope that no one from your employer finds out about either of these threads as they will not look kindly upon you taking this internal issue public."

I think this would be a BEST case scenario.  If I was one of these managing directors, and I saw either of these posts, I'd fire this HR person.  On. The. Spot.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to get some feedback on what can I improve to change that.

Let's avoid being personal about *you*, instead see the instance of HR that you represent. That means ignore if you have fun doing that or you realize you got the unfortunate job and have no choice.
However your name and facts you give suggest you really are too far from rational behavior, as well as the rules you are checking are... but let us only see the situation.

Summarizing the post you refer to, someone works from home because of an injury - instead sick leave.
This person gets crutches suggested, with all trouble it brings to commute every day.
All managers are activated and the employee is threatened with termination although their manager is fine with that.
That's a situation completely out of every sanity.

There may be rules - made by someone far from reality and sense. But nobody likes that.
Hence, perhaps the downvotes come because you keep digging deeper and deeper.

Comment: But isn't it his job to do so ? The rules might be overkill, but if it is his job to enforce them, then he is 100% right, and will still most likely be fired.

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t According to the linked posting his "boss doesn't want to pursue the matter further". Taking this into account as well as the fact that other managers don't see a problem too, then is it really his job? If I was the one unable to walk properly, nevertheless doing my work instead of be on sick leave, I'd try to move this person out of their job along with me, if nothing else helps.

Comment: I get what you're saying loud and clear, but if I'm told to do my job and when I do everyone shrugs it off it makes you feel pretty useless and very bitter and punish the person who is not following said guidelines

Comment: Are you doing your job if "boss doesn't want to pursue the matter further" but you keep doing it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to give it up for your own mental health. You have lost. Stop trying to extend the dispute by finding new people to pester, because everybody will say the same thing. You are wrong. Posting here will achieve nothing. Do not do it.

Instead, ask yourself why everybody is disagreeing with you. Consider whether you are wrong, and whether this is something you should devote any more energy to. Sometimes you just have to give up and move on. Ideally, you will be able to see other people's points of view, but if not, just put it behind you and do the rest of your job. Maybe take a vacation.

People reading this will be aware that there are strange people who become obsessed with something that everybody else knows is untrue: some of them believe in aliens or weird cultish religions, that science is a lie, the earth is flat, space travel a hoax, or the universe is only explicable by visualising time as a cube. Others believe more mundane things that are almost certainly incorrect and definitely nothing they can influence. These strange people spend the rest of their lives doing things like printing pamphlets and self-publishing books and handing them out on the street, running purple-texted websites, or in extreme cases they do much worse things to try and attract attention or take revenge. It is in our interest and your interest that you stop and think what you are doing and where it will take you.

Answer (score 4):

As I told you in a comment, I think you clearly lack HR job training.

Sadly there is no such thing as HR education, HR apprenticeship or HR college classes. Which is a shame, given that your "workers" probably all would not have been employed if they did not have a multi year education in their respective professions.

I have not downvoted your question personally, but "lacks basic job training" could be seen as "no prior research" when asking why something basic on the job does not work as expected.

Comment: There is education for HR, at least in the Netherlands I worked with HR people who studied - loosely translated - labour and organisation psychology.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Our HR people are, best case, economics majors who had a course or two on HR issues as something they had to sit through.

Comment: In the US, there are Bachelor Degrees in Human Resources from schools like Cornell, Penn State and Rutgers.

Comment: HR is also included in many undergraduate degree courses on management and similar subjects; some management degrees in the UK allow you to specialise in HR management.

Comment: Not that it should require specialised HR training to understand why "he can just use crutches" is a bad idea.